# What is Java Error: Java Runtime class file version

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

I'm trying to compile an old Java project under Android Studio Dolphin 2021.1.3.1.  The error is

*Cause: com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction has been compiled
by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0),
this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0*

**What does this mean and how can I fix it?**

DETAILS:
I'm running Win10/64bit on a Dell 9010.
JAVA_HOME is set to c:\Program Files(X86)\Java\jre1.8.0_361 (exists)
Android Studio Dolphin 2021.1.3.1

Answer (score 1):

This error message indicates that the `com/android/tools/idea/gradle/run/OutputBuildAction` class was compiled with a more recent version of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) than the one you are currently using.

Class file version 55.0 corresponds to Java 11, while class file version 52.0 corresponds to Java 8.

To fix this issue, you can try updating your `JRE` to a more recent version that supports class file version 55.0 or higher.

> You can download the latest version of the JRE from the [Java SE Downloads page](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).

After installing the new `JRE`, make sure to update your `JAVA_HOME` environment variable to point to the new installation directory. You may also need to update the PATH environment variable to include the bin directory of the new `JRE` installation.
Once you have updated your `JRE` and environment variables, try building your project again in Android Studio.